# Exposing an Elusive Program Crash - Crash Dump Issue

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, pinvoke, crash-dumps

On Windows 10 and using Visual Studio 2015, I'm trying to debug a WPF C# application that incorporates C++ PInvokes.  After the app starts, a particular execution path causes the app to crash, which then shows this message:

> vshost32.exe has stopped working
>   A problem caused the program to stop working correctly.  Windows will close the program and notify you if the solution is available.

I take the "Debug" option provided on that dialogue, and then it says:

> A debugger is attached to MyWpfApp.exe but not configured to debug this unhandled exception.  To debug this exception, detach the current debugger.

This is frustrating.  When the crash occurs, it is being debugged by Visual Studio 2015.  Why is it "not configured to debug" this problem?  Can the configuration be modified to catch this?

At this point I'm stuck.  I tried issuing a "detach all" command to VS 2015, so that the OS can start a new debugger, but VS 2015 refuses to detach.  If I instead simply *stop* VS2015, then the OS says that the crash can no longer be debugged, because the process was terminated.

In short, I can't debug the problem - even though I have best-in-the-industry tools pointed directly at it.

Any suggestions of how to debug this mysterious crash?

I do have additional information about this problem, because I also tried to debug it on a Windows 7 machine within Visual Studio 2013.  It has the same crash.  In this case, the crash simply causes the debug session in VS 2013 to suddenly end without warning - as if the program had terminated gracefully.  In an effort to capture the crash, I activated [crash dump capture via Windows Error Reporting (WER)](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2013/05/how-to-debug-silent-crashes-in-net.html).

It worked!  First, I got this info:

> Unhandled exception at 0x77BC46A9 (msvcr120.dll) in MyWpfApp.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.

The stack trace then showed me the exact line of managed code that transitions into unmanaged, and eventually reaches msvcr120 which crashes.

Unfortunately, after this initial success, my debugging success ended here because suddenly the WER configuration on the Windows 7 development machine simply stopped capturing any further crashes.  I thought it was code changes I had made which jinxed WER, but when I reverted my changes WER continued to be unaware that the application was crashing.

So in the end, this crash is doing its best to be untrappable - preventing me from capturing a crash dump.  I also tried running the app from the command prompt, and attaching [sysinternals procdump](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) to it:

```
c:\>procdump -ma -e -accepteula -x . MyWpfApp.exe
```

Surprisingly, this also didn't work.  The OS caught the crash and reported it, while procdump was entirely unaware the crash had occurred.

Is there a "bigger hammer" I can use that will ensure I can capture crash dumps?

Comment: maybe enable application verifier for process in question and attach a kernel debugger? I'm however afraid that managed stack trace will be pure garbage.

Comment: Can you run the application in non-debug mode with WINDBG?  WINDBG sees everything and is easier to manipulate unmanaged dumps. The only problem with WINDBG is that it is a huge learning curve.  But it is everything including the ability to debug using SOS for managed code all in the same session.